# How to create my own HTTP 200 result class?

Tags: python, cherrypy

In CherryPy, I can `raise cherrypy.HTTPError(code, message)` when something goes wrong, or I `return string` when it all works out.

What I am looking for now, is how can I create a class, so that I can do this:

```
class MyOwnResultClass:
   foo = None

   def __init__(self, foo):
      self.foo = foo

   def __str__(self):
      return "Result: {f}".format(f=self.foo)

class cherrypystuff(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return MyOwnResultClass("f")
```

This fails with the error

> TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

And I have to use `return str(MyOwnResultClass("f")`.

Comment: What's your motivation? I think, you understand cherrypy's philosophy wrong. Anyway, you could use a decorator.

Comment: @webKnjaZ the motivation is that I want to be able to use my own class to create a reply that always looks the same (in this case `Result: <result>`). Could you elaborate on the CherryPy philosophy, where do I get it wrong?

Comment: Why do you need a class for that? Zen of CherryPy is simplicity.

Comment: @webKnjaZ in that case, I will have to put `return "Result: <result>"` in each handler. Which is repeated code and never good.

Comment: Use decorator for this

Comment: @webKnjaZ how does that work? Could you post an answer with a little more info?

Comment: Please check my reply below, it should work for you.

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what the problem is with `return MyOwnResultClass("f")`? I think this would make the question more useful for others trying something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dived a little more into the error message, and apparently, CherryPy wants an iterable object as return type, if not a string.

So, the solution is quite simple: make the `MyOwnResultClass` iterable:

```
class MyOwnResultClass:
   foo = None

   def __init__(self, foo):
      self.foo = foo

   def __iter__(self):
      yield "Result: {f}".format(f=self.foo)
```

**Update** after seeing the talk suggested by @webKnjaZ, I refactored to this:

```
def MyOwnResult(foo):
    yield "Result: {f}".format(f=foo)
```

Comment: @webKnjaZ great talk, how would I refactor the above code to do so?

Comment: I'd suggest you using decorator as I posted in my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43719569/595220 . You may move it into separate module (say `utils`) and then reuse it where you want.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with.

```
from functools import wraps

import cherrypy

RESPONSE_TEMPLATE = 'Result: {res}'

def resultify(original_handler):
    @wraps(original_handler)
    def wrapped_handler(*args, **kwargs):
        orig_resp = original_handler()
        return RESPONSE_TEMPLATE.format(res=orig_resp)
    return wrapped_handler

class CherryPyStuff(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @resultify
    def index(self):
        return 'f'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try renaming your __str__ method to __repr__ ... I think that should work for what you're attempting.